# Printing in console

Tags: ios, xcode

Print something in console usually is fast (<1s) but recently I started working on a project and the print time is huge (>20s).
(for example putting a "Print("bla")" in the code will work fine, but printing through the console is slow)

Any ideas what might cause this?

[image]

This happens in Xcode 7,8 (and I don't remember if 9 also, but I think so). Also it's reproducible regardless of simulator/device.

This only happens for the 1st time I try to print, then it works fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same here im my project for a while. Sometimes I get an error while trying do get some variable value too. Have no idea, tried everything on the web to solve

Comment: Xcode 8 or 9? Does the delay happen only on the 1st `po ...` after which it's quick as expected, or is it always slow? I assume you've cleaned the project and cleared the Derived Data folder?

Comment: Is this happening on the simulator, a wirelessly connected debugging device or a usb connected debugging device?

Comment: @DonMag and @ ekscrypto I've updated the question with the answers to your questions. (and yes I cleaned the Derived Data)

Comment: hmmm... Are you seeing this delay on a big, lots-of-code, project? Or do you also see it on a fresh project?

Comment: big project. if I create a new prj it will work fine

Comment: I also see this same behavior, on a **very** large enterprise project that's mixed Swift and Objective-C (Xcode 8.3). My first attempt to view a value in a given run takes 20 or 30 seconds, and then everything after that is fast.